# MCP3008 Installation Issues

Tags: spi, analog-to-digital

[image]

[image]

CH5 is connected to my AO from my moisture sensor.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /dev/spi*
crw-rw---- 1 root spi 153, 0 Jun 18 12:13 /dev/spidev0.0
crw-rw---- 1 root spi 153, 1 Jun 18 12:13 /dev/spidev0.1
```

Check if spidev is available

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
sha256_generic          9839  1
hmac                    3211  1
drbg                   12876  1
ctr                     4101  1
ccm                     9008  1
arc4                    2076  2
rt2800usb              18877  0
rt2800lib              82155  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00usb              12680  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              48998  3 rt2x00usb,rt2800lib,rt2800usb
mac80211              608549  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
cfg80211              499234  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
crc_ccitt               1732  1 rt2800lib
rfkill                 21397  2 cfg80211
snd_bcm2835            23163  0
snd_pcm                95441  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_timer              22396  1 snd_pcm
snd                    68368  3 snd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm
spi_bcm2835             8032  0
bcm2835_gpiomem         3823  0
bcm2835_wdt             4133  0
uio_pdrv_genirq         3718  0
uio                    10230  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
w1_therm                4475  0
w1_gpio                 4534  0
wire                   31801  2 w1_gpio,w1_therm
cn                      5860  1 wire
i2c_dev                 6578  0
fuse                   89800  1
ipv6                  367607  24
```

I guess I can check here if spi is enanabled.

And this is the python code I'm trying to run

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  8 2015, 00:52:26)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mcp3008
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mcp3008
```

Or in a python file

```
from time import sleep
import mcp3008

while True:
    m = mcp3008.readadc(5)
    print "Moisture level: {:>5} ".format(m)
    sleep(.5)
```

which yields

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/GPIOProjects $ sudo python mcptest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mcptest.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mcp3008
ImportError: No module named mcp3008
```

It did work yesterday and I got some readings. I then went on to write some python scrip to output on my HD44780 LCD. I may have rebooted during this, however since then I wasn't able to talk to the MCP3008.

My raspi-blacklist.confi looks like this

```
blacklist i2c-bcm2708
```

Version

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/GPIOProjects $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.4.13+ #894 Mon Jun 13 12:43:26 BST 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

OS Version

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

I did activate SPI & SPI Kernel in Advanced Options

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @Milliways Raspbian

Comment: I repeat What OS are you using - specifically which version?

Comment: @Milliways I added the information if that is the correct command. I'm new to RPi

Comment: The reason I asked is to confirm you are using Jessie, which uses Device Tree. You should not have a `blacklist` (although it serves some purpose in special circumstances). I do not know what "activate SPI Kernel" is supposed to mean. No mere mortal can read your wiring diagram, and couldn't be expected to look up the data sheets to see if it is correct. You have omitted the most important info to let someone help - namely the Python code you are trying to execute. Also DON'T paste images paste the text - it is much easier to read.

Comment: @Milliways Should I delete the blacklist file? "Activate SPI" means that if you use hardware spi you have to enable SPI modules under Advanced Options in the rpi config. Regarding the diagram, this was my 1st time using the program. Do the different colors help? I did not omit the python code since I can't even import the mcp3008. But I added the section for you! What can I do about the device tree?

Comment: The error message gives you the error.  There is no module called mcp3008.  Presumably you created or downloaded this module and put it into your local directory.  You will need to do that again.

Comment: @joan Thank you! I also redid the wiring (will have to check if anything changed from my original setup) and made sure the mcp3008.py is in the same directory. It was not obvious to me that I import that py file. I thought I would import the ADC with that function from all connected devices. You solved that misconception. If you'd like you can make it an answer or I'll see if I also changed my wiring and answer myself.

Comment: Good.  It's simplest if you answer yourself.